# Delete Object property from a list but not the whole index

Tags: c#

Was searching through the for this answer but didn't find any answer.

Is there a way to remove only one of the properties from specific index of a list? is it event possible?

So if I have a list:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
```

where:

```
public class Person
{
    #region Public Properties

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

and let's say we have three indexes and every one of those indexes contains x of properties:

1. Name: 'Bob' Age: 21
2. Name: 'Sarah' Age 19
3. Name: 'Mary' Age 29

Is it possible to delete, for example name 'Sarah' but not the age which is '19'?

I was trying to do it this way but didn't have any luck as it deleted the whole index instead of only the name:

```
people.RemoveAll(p => p.Name == "Sarah")
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. The things in the list are `Person` objects. You can add and remove `Person` objects from the list. It doesn't make sense to talk about removing a "property" from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to delete, for example name 'Sarah' but not the age which is '19'?

Not using the code you posted, it's not. The values `"Sarah"` and `19` are intrinsically bound, by virtue of both being declared members of the `Person` class. Any instance of `Person` will *always* have a value for both its `Name` and `Age` properties.

Depending on what you're actually trying to do (your question is fairly vague), you may find it useful to just set the `Name` property `null`. Then other code can use the `null` value to indicate "this property doesn't exist". The property will still actually be there, and will have a value. But the value will be `null` and so the rest of your code can ignore it as if it didn't exist, on that basis.

Another way to approach the problem is to stored objects that don't have a pre-declared set of properties. For example, you could store the data as dictionaries. This is, frankly, not advisable because you will lose all the advantages of static (compile-time) type-safety and property naming. But it can be done. It would look something like this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> people = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>()
    {
        new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "Name", "Bob" },
                { "Age", 21}
            },
        new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "Name", "Sarah" },
                { "Age", 19 }
            },
        new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "Name", "Mary" },
                { "Age", 29 }
            },
    };
```

Then if you have a specific index you want to remove the name but not the age from:

```
int index = ...;

people[index].RemoveKey("Name");
```

Comment: Super! Thanks for the brief explanation and the two examples. Decided to try the first solution and it worked, when 'Sarah' is null the age still stays the same. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is what I think you need:

```
people.Where(person => person.Age == 19)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(person => person.Name = null);
```

Comment: There is no indication that the search is based on the age. You might as well just set the `Name` property of the element in the list by index, as the OP's indicated. And materializing a whole new `List<T>` object just to call `ForEach()` when one's already got a `List<T>` in hand is very wasteful. `people.ForEach(p => p.Name = p.Age == 19 ? null : p.Name)` (or some equivalent) would make a lot more sense.